# how to apply a rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have to create a condition for redirecting a website to other URL and I think it is quite complicated condition.

```
#RewriteRule (pl)?(/page/5/?)$  /polityka-prywatnosci/ [R=301,L]
```

That's my base for this redirect, but I need to exclude some words preceding `/page/5/` for example word 'car' to not execute this redirect when this word appears. To make everything clear:
when Ive got: `http://some-url/page/5` I want to redirect this to `http://some-url/polityka-prywatnosci/`
but when there is `http://some-url/car/page/5` i want to stay in this URL.
I tried such trick as: `#RewriteRule (pl)?[^(car)](/page/5/?)$  /polityka-prywatnosci/ [R=301,L]` but it doesnt work. What are the possibilities to overcome it?

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

If negative lookbehind is allowed, you can try with:

```
RewriteRule (?<!car|car/pl)(/pl)?(/page/5/?)$  /polityka-prywatnosci/ [R=301,L]
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tK2hJ7/1).

Another way could be to state 3 consecutive replacements:

```
RewriteRule (/page/5/?)$  /polityka-prywatnosci/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule (car|car/pl)/polityka-prywatnosci/$  $1/page/5/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule /pl(/polityka-prywatnosci/)$  $1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thanks for that, but Im afriad it's not allowed in htaccess/

Comment: @MarekCzyż Now I'm seeing other questions on the same topic and lookbehind seems to be allowed. Anyway, I've updated the answer: do you think it can work?

Comment: I think that no, because htaccess search for first matching replacement and then leave it @horcrux

Comment: I've noticed that .htaccess doesn't accept this part of rule: '(?<1....'. -> to be precise this character "<".